# How do I stop plt.ylabel() from rendering an empty frame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

When I do this in Jupyter Notebook, python 3.53:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.ylabel('yvals')
```

I get an empty chart that I don't want.  In the next step I render the actual chart and then I have two of them. How do I avoid rendering the first chart?

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `plt.ylabel('yvals')` after your `plt.plot`.

Comment: I also suggest using %matplotlib notebook, it usually works better for me.

Answer (score 0):

That did the trick:

```
df.plot(kind='area')
plt.ylabel('yvals')
```

Comment: You should accept his answer, and delete this answer, if you like his answer :)